# Is there a way to use a COUNTIFS equivalent in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a table that would have the number of times a certain event fired for a user. As we collect different event_params which differ by where an event fired, I wouldn't want to have some events simply aggregated under the COUNTIF function.

Example: qr_interaction event consists of event_name = 'qr_click' and event_param view = 'qr_screen'
Outcome table:

| user_id | qr_interactions |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 16 |
| 112 | 3 |

I've tried a few COUNTIF or COUNT variations, but no success

`COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(event_name, 'QR|qr|Qr')) AS qr_interactions` - works

`COUNTIF(event_name = 'tap_navigation' AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(type, 'card|profile|settings|clubs')) AS admin_navigation` - does not work

Comment: Can you share the part of the query of what you have tried but doesn't work? I'm not sure I understand what the problem with countif() could be here?

Comment: to give an example: COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(event_name, 'QR|qr|Qr')) AS qr_interactions - works COUNTIF(event_name = 'tap_navigation' AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(type, 'card|profile|settings|clubs')) AS admin_navigation - doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

I'm gonna make some assumptions and use the public ga4 data to show how to query ga4 parameters:

parameters are in the `event_params` array, so you need to unnest that if you want to query it:

```sql
SELECT  

  countif(
    event_name='page_view' 
    AND 
    exists(select 1 from unnest(event_params) 
      where key='page_title' and value.string_value='Home'
    ) 
  ) as home_page_views,

  countif(
    event_name='click' 
    AND 
    exists(select 1 from unnest(event_params) 
      where key='link_url' and value.string_value like '%fedex%'
    ) 
  ) as follow_link_to_fedex

FROM `bigquery-public-data.ga4_obfuscated_sample_ecommerce.events_20210131`
```

Writing a subquery on the event_params array should be the easiest. `unnest()` turns an array into a relation (table format) so you can run SQL on it.